# Is my solution to "MacPOW 1141: Capturing 5 integers" correct?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

<sub>Crossposted from [P.SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/123539/is-my-solution-to-macpow-1141-capturing-5-integers-correct) as it was closed because I sort of forgot the difference between a math puzzle and a math problem</sub>

<sub>Source: [MacPOW 1141](https://stanwagon.com/potw/fall11/p1141.html)</sub>

"MacPOW 1141: Capturing 5 integers" states:

> For which positive real numbers $x$ are there exactly 5 integers $n$ such that the following statement is true?$$x<n<x^2$$

I got that $x\in(\sqrt7,\sqrt8]\cup\{3\}$.

How I got this:

1. First, one can notice 3 is a valid solution ($3\lt4,5,6,7,8\lt9$) and that $\sqrt8\approx2.82$ is also a valid solution ($\sqrt8\lt3,4,5,6,7\lt8$).
2. Now, here's the thing: any number $\sqrt8\lt x\lt 3$ will have 6 integers between $x$ and $x^2$: $x\lt3,4,5,6,7,8\lt x^2$.
3. Now, to check $\sqrt7$: $\sqrt7\lt3,4,5,6\lt7$. However, since any number just larger than $\sqrt7$ has exactly 5 integers between $x$ and $x^2$ (such as Euler's number $e$), we have that $x\in(\sqrt7,\sqrt8]\cup\{3\}$
4. Lastly, I plugged all of my tests up to that point into [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/efyjk3blfz) to check if there was anything that I had missed.

However, I don't know if my solution is correct or not, so my question is:

**Is my solution correct, and if not, what solutions in $\mathbb R^+$ did I miss?**